# Loop through table jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table

Here is my code

```
$('#myTable tr').each(function() {
          if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row
          var orderpercust = this.cells[7].innerHTML;
          if(orderpercust == 1){
            total_order_1++;
          }else if(orderpercust == 2){
            total_order_2++;
          }else if(orderpercust > 2){
            total_order_gt_2++;
          }
      });
```

The problem is it only loop through 1 page of the table, I want it to loop until the end of the page in table. Any suggestion?

Comment: Write code to navigate through pages of the table.

Comment: Are you using pagination? and in DOM only first page is loaded at a time?

Comment: @stud3nt how to navigate through pages of the table?

Comment: @palaѕн all data loaded at a time and pagination is created at the backend

Comment: If the pagination is coming from the server side, then the client only receives one page of data at a time. As such the client cannot loop through all data as it has not received it. You will need to calculate this value server side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan got the idea, thanks.